# print in GDB,how to examine a register?

Tags: assembly, gdb, cpu-registers

So, what is the difference between

1) `print /x * (int*)($ebp)`
 2) `print /x (int*)($ebp)`
 3) `print /x $ebp`

It seems that the 2nd one has is the same as the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 prints the value of register epb. (by default its type is void*).

2 prints the same value of ebp, but cast to int* type. It's still the same address.

1 finally prints the integer value stored at *ebp (memory with the address in ebp).